# jQuery & animate.css for scrollReveal

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop, animate.css

I have been trying to create a reveal on Scroll effect, I have tried multiple plugins but I can't seem to find any of them that fit what I'm looking and if they do Im not to sure on how to implement it effectively to do what I want it do.

I have got this piece of JavaScript code which I have been playing around with;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            $('.hideme').each(function(i){
                var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop(); + $(window).height();
                if(bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object){
                    $(this).addClass('animated fadeInUp', 1000);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The problem is that the animation is only added once it's off the screen so I have to scroll past where I would like the animation to take effect for it to actually work. I'm not to sure on how to make the JS implement the animate.css code as soon as the element is in view of the window/browser.

Also another thing I have been trying to do is remove the class with jQuery (removeClass) method, but it just hides and the show's the items without animating.

I have used a gif to illustrate my problem (sorry for it being so small).
[image]

There is also a JsFiddle to further illustrate my problem;
https://jsfiddle.net/1hwpswow/

Comment: replace
`var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop(); + $(window).height();`
to
`var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();`
not work? 
It seem you have tried,because you forget to remove the delimeter

Comment: Hi Carr, I did try this yes but it's still doing exactly the same thing. I think the line of code I need to change is the bottom_of_object variable I need it to target the top of the element/object not the bottom so that when I scroll it will trigger before I have scrolled past the element and not after. Not sure how to achieve this exactly though. thanks.

Comment: Let  **bottom_of_object**  just be  **$(this).offset().top** wouldn't meet your need?

Comment: Hi Carr, I did try that as well. However I want the elements to animate when each tile appears from the bottom of the window. So I would need to target the top of the object to appear when it reaches the bottom of the window. Doing it the way you suggested is what I'm looking but it does from the top of the window/browser and not the bottom.

Comment: I have post aan answer below , not sure whether meet your need , hopes that would help you ~

Answer (score 0):

Anímate css works with opacity, you set the opacity to 0 and the animation should work! Also, you must remove and add the class of the animate css every time you use it!

Comment: Hi Db, I understand what your saying but this isn't the problem. The problem is trying to get each tile to animate or fadeInUp whenever one of those tiles reaches the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Set a margin-top in begin and remove it after you scroll through a complete 
distance equal to window's height . here is a fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/Carr1005/1hwpswow/2/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.hideme').eq(0).css('margin-top',$(window).height());    
    $(window).scroll(function(){

      console.log($(window).scrollTop());
      console.log($(window).height());
      if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(window).height())
        $('.hideme').eq(0).css('margin-top',0);

      $('.hideme').each(function(i){

        var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top;
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                if(bottom_of_window > top_of_object){
                    $(this).addClass('animated fadeInUp', 1000);
                }

            });

        });
    });
```